# Geoserver-backend webpage won't show up in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, geoserver

I have an HTML webpage (HTTPS enabled, behind Nginx server at Ubuntu 20.04) that connects with Geoserver WMS layer of a region of interest to show 2D spatial points. The web page works fine in my web browser and also in mobile phone web browser. I am trying to show the same webpage in Android web view. In return, the webpage is zoomed over wrong location (waters, likely empty map) and won't show 2D points. Only legends and map layers control are shown.

I have been googling and finding different answers on StackOverflow but none related to my problem. Does anyone have any idea why webView doesn't show the webpage / 2D points?

Interestingly, I also can not see the location map in the Emulator > Settings > Location UI. I reckon this could be the potential problem. The Google Maps and Google Play Services in the Emulator are updated. I am using API Level 30.

The following is the logcat when I run the app. In the following, "DateTime" replaces the actual data time, which can be ignored.

```
 DateTime29:49.935 9270-9293/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf45161b0, tid 9293
    DateTime29:49.948 9270-9293/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime29:50.071 9270-9293/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    DateTime29:50.073 9270-9293/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf4516270, tid 9293
    DateTime29:50.099 9270-9293/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime29:56.951 9270-9344/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf451d0b0, tid 9344
    DateTime29:56.999 9270-9344/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime30:29.178 9401-9424/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf450d930, tid 9424
    DateTime30:29.186 9401-9424/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime30:29.295 9401-9424/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    DateTime30:29.296 9401-9424/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf450db10, tid 9424
    DateTime30:29.329 9401-9424/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime30:35.508 9401-9472/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf4520950, tid 9472
    DateTime30:35.533 9401-9472/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime32:06.145 1097-1218/? I/NearbyConnections: Client 79943429 requested advertising to stop.
    DateTime32:06.237 1097-1218/? I/NearbyConnections: Client 79943429 requested advertising to start.
    DateTime32:06.240 1097-3944/? I/NearbyConnections: Generated local endpoint id 62NO for client 79943429
    DateTime32:06.240 1097-3944/? I/NearbyConnections: In startBleAdvertising([ 0x32 0x03 0x27 0x29 0x9e 0x3f 0x0a 0x6d 0x8e 0xd0 0x04 0x64 0x09 0x21 0x8a 0xab 0xe4 ]), client 79943429 not allowed to listen for incoming BLE connections to ServiceID NearbySharing
    DateTime34:00.943 9892-9914/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf450d930, tid 9914
    DateTime34:00.971 9892-9914/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime34:01.083 9892-9914/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    DateTime34:01.083 9892-9914/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf450e350, tid 9914
    DateTime34:01.125 9892-9914/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime34:07.714 9892-9963/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf451f690, tid 9963
    DateTime34:07.793 9892-9963/com.example.myappD/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    DateTime45:39.387 1097-1218/? I/NearbyConnections: Client 79943429 requested advertising to stop.
    DateTime45:39.458 1097-1218/? I/NearbyConnections: Client 79943429 requested advertising to start.
    DateTime45:39.460 1097-9596/? I/NearbyConnections: Generated local endpoint id O7XR for client 79943429
    DateTime45:39.461 1097-9596/? I/NearbyConnections: In startBleAdvertising([ 0x32 0x72 0xca 0x9e 0x87 0x83 0x8e 0xc7 0xe6 0x2c 0x01 0x91 0xb2 0x93 0x6c 0x03 0x7a ]), client 79943429 not allowed to listen for incoming BLE connections to ServiceID NearbySharing
```

**Update 1**

Basically, I am using this infamous [BetterWMS](https://gist.github.com/alfredotranchedone/72326145ecff5d7d7233) approach. The HTML page simply points to the server running Geoserver, WMS mapping and `GetFeatureInfo`. All works fine in the PC and mobile phone web browsers. Here are the request parameters in the HTML (`getLegendGraphic`) which gets plotted in the Android webView. But not the WMS layers itself which gets zoomed over "the middle of the nowhere". The getFeatureInfo details can be seen in the above link.

```
  var url = 'https://my_server/geoserver/cite/wms';
      
        wmsPane = map.createPane('wmsPane');
        wmsPane.style.zIndex = 250;
      
      L.tileLayer.betterWms(url, {
        layers: 'my_layer:my_layer',
        transparent: true,
        tiled: true,
        format: 'image/png',
        pane: wmsPane
      }).addTo(map);
      uri = "https://my_server/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=35&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=cite:my_layer&format_options=layout:legend&legend_options=fontAntiAliasing:true",
      L.wmsLegend(uri);
```

And here is the getMap request that works fine in My PC web browser and also in Android Emulator (it takes a while but loads in webView).

```
https://my_server/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=cite%3Alayer&bbox=442190.0%2C6049851.0%2C892642.0%2C6401710.0&width=768&height=599&srs=EPSG%3A32632&styles=&format=application/openlayers
```

I still think whether there is something going wrong in the webView due to location maps not working in the map UI (Emulator > Settings > Location)

Comment: Can you add the URLs being requested by the working and non-working apps? Just the request parameters will be fine

Comment: @IanTurton: I have edited the question with more details concerning the request parameters and the `getFeatureInfo` method I am using. Again, all works fine in PC and mobile phone browsers.

Comment: I need to see the getmap requests, so the actual values sent by android compared to the web browser

Comment: @IanTurton: Alright, I also added the `getMap` request, which works fine in my web browser and also in Android Emulator's webview. The same getMap data is loaded and clickable via getFeatureInfo.

Comment: @IanTurton: I figured that there is a difference in SRS Bounding Box in the two getMap requests. So the one that works fine has the correct bounding box, but the one that fails has this in the getMap request response in the Geoserver log: `RawKvp = {TILED=true, REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT=image/png, SRS=EPSG:3857, BBOX=0,-9783.939620502508,4891.96981025128,-4891.969810250948, VERSION=1.1.1, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=256, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=cite:layer}`

Comment: The thing I do not understand is whether is it Emulator's problem or the WMS + getFeatureInfo setup problem. The emulator problem (wrong bounding box) is also replicated in my physical device / test mobile phone.

Comment: I would guess it is the emulator, you need to work out why the bbox is different