# Uncaught Exception Error: Missing Google maps in Android's Emulator Location UI and wrong bounding box

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am on Windows 11 and using Android Studio 4.0.1 (don't ask why I haven't updated yet!). I have an HTML webpage served from the HTTPS-enabled Nginx server serving some Geoserver data (getMap and getFeatureInfo). The webpage works fine in PC and mobile phone web browsers. Via my previous unsolved question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77681698/geoserver-backend-webpage-wont-show-up-in-android-studio-emulator?noredirect=1#comment136965641_77681698), the issue seems to be related to Android Emulator.

The problem is the same webpage won't show up in Android webView. Researching the issue reveals that wrong bounding box coordinates are sent to Geoserver (seen in the server backend log) from the Android Emulator.

```
RawKvp = {TILED=true, REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT=image/png, SRS=EPSG:3857, BBOX=0,-9783.939620502508,4891.96981025128,-4891.969810250948, VERSION=1.1.1, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=256, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=cite:layer}
```

I also can not see Google Maps in the location UI of the Emulator.

[image: Missing maps in location UI]

In addition, during this event, I see the following two errors in the EventLog.

```
Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key="longHEXKey...FWF4Kohsf1V....sFY"&callback=initMap:97, (null))

Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key="longHexKey....V49aFWF4Kohsf1VS...."&callback=initMap:97, (null))
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error and whether emulator going crazy is due to this reason.

Some info about my installed setup:

```
SDK Platforms: Android 10.0 and 9.0 (API 29 and 28)
SDK Tools: Android Emulator, Platform-tools v 30.0.04, Intel x86 HAXM installer
Compile SDK: 29
Emulator AVD System Image API 29
```

Google Maps app is installed in the Emulator (updated it recently) and I can open and see the maps there, just not in location UI.

How can I resolve this error and make location UI work? which will also hopefully resolve emulator's wrong bounding box problem.